# sending project into personal iDevice

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an iPhone 4S with iOS 5.0.1 and also have xcode 4.2. When I try to build & run my app in my iDevice instead of iOS 5.0 Simulator, it pops-up error like this: "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version." so is there any way to send my app into my own iphone?

Comment: Have you paid Apple the $99 and become a member of the IOS development program?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure your device has a provision profile installed that includes the device's UDID and the app's ID. If you're fairly new to iOS development and haven't installed one of your apps on a device before, you'll definitely want to go through the instructions in the iOS developer portal -- they'll walk you through the provisioning process. Also, if you've only recently updated the device to iOS 5, make sure that you [tell Xcode to use the device for development](http://www.radulucaciu.ro/upgrading-to-ios5-causing-no-provisioned-ios-devices-are-available/68/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you purchase the iOS Developer Program for 99$/year?
2. Did you register your Device with your UDID?
3. Did you install the Team Provisioning Profile on your iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test your application on an iOS device (such as an iPhone or iPad), you must create an Apple provisioning profile and developer identity. Then you'll also have to create an app ID and register your device. If you have purchased a developer profile, I highly suggest following Apple's step by step guide on how to do this.

For now, here's a guide to to the first steps:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-an-apple-development-provisioning-pr.html

Once you've created a developer profile, you can just use Apple's step by step guide